# Is there a phrasal verb with the meaning 'understand'?

Tags: phrase-requests, phrasal-verbs

Find a phrasal verb which is similar in meaning to the word "understand"

Comment: You could use 'I _get it_.'

Comment: But i am finding for a phrasal verb which is similar in meaning to understand.

Comment: *Figure out* (Neither example of *get* is phrasal. *Get* here merely means to grasp mentally, and it takes a direct object to say what's grasped.)

Comment: Tell us why you are not using _understand_ and want a variation.

Comment: get with it , get with the program (although slightly different from understand)

Comment: Agree with @YosefBaskin. Why do you specifically want a phrasal verb for this?

Comment: Please see the checklist on the [phrase-requests tag info](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/phrase-requests/info) for guidelines about what this sort of question should contain. We need quite a lot more information than is currently included, I'm afraid.

Comment: 'Make out' (transitive; obligatorily separable) and 'work out' are other MWVs with (among many other senses) the meaning 'understand'. I think they're negative polarity items though, and not formal in this usage: 'I just can't make/work Gerry out.'

Answer (score 2):

Here are some that relate to the onset of understanding.

**Dawn on** To suddenly understand.

> It dawned on me that you were right all along. (I just understood what you were saying.)

**Get through to** To make someone understand.

> I want to get through to you the importance of this last item. (I want you to understand how important this last item is.)

**Wake up to** To suddenly realize or understand.

> When will you wake up to the reasons she left you? (When will you understand why she left you?)

**Wise up** To begin to understand.

> When are you going to wise up to the facts about this case? (When will you understand what is going on in this case?)

Her is one that is similar, but has more of a continuous meaning rather than a meaning of suddenness:

**Be wise to** To know or understand.

> I am wise to the game he is playing. (I understand/know what kind of game he is playing.)

Answer (score 1):

You might use the phrase '***sink in***'.

*'Has it **sunk in**?'* = 'Do you understand it?'

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sink-in

Answer (score 1):

> *Can you **figure** it **out***? - Do you understand?

http://www.englishpage.com/prepositions/phrasaldictionaryF.html

> *Let's see if he **catches on***? - Let's see if he understands?

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/catch-on

> *I wonder if she'll **cotton on***. - I wonder if she'll understand.

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/cotton-on

> *He's **tumbled to** the fact that his quarry is his own flesh and blood* - He has understood that his quarry is his own flesh and blood.

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/tumble-to

> *Can you **keep up***? - Are you able to understand (something happening or changing very fast)?

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/keep-up

Comment: This is not a 'phrasal verb' according to any of the many conflicting definitions used. It's a verbo-nominal idiom.

Comment: Now you're piggybacking on deadrat's comment.

Comment: "get across" . . .

Comment: But quite a few minutes later!

Answer (score 1):

> **Make out** ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/make%20out))
>
> ***to find or grasp the meaning of***:
>
> - tried to make out what had really happened.
> - I can't quite make out what she is trying to say.